# CMake header files not being found in include

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I have library, AprilTags, that uses cmake top build it.

I have another project AIV, that uses AprilTags. I want to keep the apriltags library inside of ~/aiv/apriltags but have another file, front_back_camera_demo that uses some of the files inside of AprilTags library.

So the file structure looks like

```
~/aiv/build/
     /apriltags/CMakeLists.txt
     /apriltags/AprilTags/TagDetector.h
     /apriltags/AprilTags/*.h
     /front_back_camera_demo.cpp
     /CMakeLists.txt
```

When I run cmake on the top level CMakeLists.txt, it builds the AprilTags library successfully, but then I get a

> front_back_camera_demo.cpp:72:35: fatal error: AprilTags/TagDetector.h: No such file or directory

error on the line where I include AprilTags/TagDetector.h

Here are the two relevant CMakeLists.txt:

Top level:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(AIV)

add_subdirectory(apriltags)
add_executable(front_back_camera_demo front_back_camera_demo.cpp 
Serial.cpp)
target_link_libraries(front_back_camera_demo apriltags)
```

Inside apriltags:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(apriltags)

#add_definitions(-pg) #"-fopenmp)

# pull in the pods macros. See cmake/pods.cmake for documentation
set(POD_NAME apriltags)
include(cmake/pods.cmake)

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "src/*.cc")
include_directories(AprilTags . /opt/local/include)
add_library(apriltags ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(OpenCV)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(apriltags ${OpenCV_LIBS}) #-pg) #-fopenmp)
pods_use_pkg_config_packages(apriltags eigen3)

if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
  target_link_libraries(apriltags -L/opt/local/lib/) # MacPorts 
special treatment...
else (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
  pods_use_pkg_config_packages(apriltags libv4l2)
endif (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")

pods_install_libraries(apriltags)

file(GLOB header_files "AprilTags/*.h")
pods_install_headers(${header_files} DESTINATION AprilTags/)

pods_install_pkg_config_file(apriltags
    LIBS -lapriltags
    REQUIRES eigen3 opencv2
    VERSION 1.0.0)

add_subdirectory(example)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can tell you that the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` needs to pass `-I ${top_srcdir}/apriltags` to the compiler, but I don't know how to tell cmake that, and I may have spelled `${top_srcdir}` incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer the `target_*` commands.

apriltags/CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_include_directories(apriltags
  PUBLIC
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
  PRIVATE
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/AprilTags"
    /opt/local/include)
```

That says, everything that uses the `apriltags` target will be able to access any includes in ".", that `apriltags` can also use "." and only `apriltags` itself uses content under the "AprilTags" and "/opt/local/include" directories.

If you really know what you are doing, you can get even more fine-grained by using generator expressions, but that is not necessary here to get it working.